# Cannot get 1 object from Json response

Tags: json, function, go

I am a beginner to Golang. Can you help me with call of function.
Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type Info struct {
    Name string  `json:"name"`
    Year float64 `json:"year,string"`
}

func (b *Base) GetInfo() (Info, error) {
    var resp Info
    path := "example.com"

    return resp, http.Get(path)
}

func main() {
    test, err := Base.GetInfo()
    fmt.Println(test, err)

}
```

Output:

```
{Name Bob Year 10}
```

How I can get only `"Bob"` ?

And If my response contains more objects example

```
{Name Bob Year 10}{Name Jane Year 2}.
```

How I can get only names? Didnt understand how to decode it or call.

Comment: [Take the Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1). And also this `return resp, http.Get(path)` is never gonna compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.` parameter to get name from resp like

```
func main() {
    test, err := Base.GetInfo()
    fmt.Println(test.Name, err)
}
```

But if there are multiple fields. Then you should save them in array of struct `Info` as:

```
func (b *Base) GetInfo() ([]Info, error) {
    var resp []Info
    path := "example.com"
    return resp, http.Get(path)
}

func main() {
    test, err := Base.GetInfo()
    fmt.Println(test[0].Name, err)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `test.Name` rather than `test.name`? I mean, the struct `Info` has a `Name` field not `name` field.